# Bash: cordova: command not found on mac

Tags: apache, cordova, npm, terminal, apache-cordova

I used command sudo npm install -g cordova to install cordova it shows result in terminal/Users/paramesh/.npm-packages/bin/cordova -> /Users/paramesh/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
+ cordova@8.0.0
updated 1 package in 47.732s

while creating project in cordova its bash: cordova not found

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's strange though that your system cannot find cordova after a global install with sudo. Have you tried reinstalling? If this doesn't help, try the following.

Restart the terminal and type this to check whether your system can find the cordova executable:

```
which cordova
```

If you get no output, it means your system cannot find the executable cordova binary. UNIX systems require executable binaries to be placed within the PATH environment variable. Try adding the following line in your ~/.bash_profile file:

```
$PATH=$PATH:/Users/paramesh/.npm-packages/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
```

If you don't have a ~/.bash_profile, add it to the ~/.bashrc or ~/.profile file, whichever exists already. Then within the terminal you want to call cordova from, type:

```
source ~/.bash_profile
which cordova
```

This should give you the location of the cordova binary. Now you can use it.

Answer (score 4):

In my case, the path of npm was not set correctly. The package was installed on my local path even if I install it globally.

First, check npm path using `npm root`

If its not `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` then

set your path using `npm config set prefix /usr/local`

and again install you package `npm install -g cordova`

Comment: I'm trying this because the path is indeed not /usr/local etc. It's users/myself/node_modules. Unfortunately though, `npm config set prefix` does not seem to be working -- Just noticed that `npm config get prefix` does return /usr/local